# What is the difference between assigning values to dictionaries explicitly, one key-pair at a time, or inline?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am generating a large JSON file using Python. I have many keys and values. I see two ways of populating my Python dictionary.

Explicitly:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['key1'] = "value1"
my_dict['key2'] = "value2"
my_dict['key3'] = "value3"
....
```

Or inline

```
my_dict = {'key1': "value1", 'key2': "value2", 'key2': "value2", ...}
```

These smaller dictionaries will be nested so neither approach is ridiculous as each inline list should be < 10 long.

From how I see it, updating with each key-value pair is more readable and easily updated in the future, but I see the inline option being used a lot so I'd like to know what the difference is.

I started with key-value pairs, but PyCharm is suggesting rewriting them to inline so that's where my doubts started.

Comment: Compare the disassembly of each. You'll see the separate assignments are doing a lot more work (a `LOAD_CONST` for each key and value, a `STORE_SUBSCR` for each map update); when you just assign the whole thing at one go it's far fewer bytecode operations.

Comment: You should not use *either* of the approaches you gave as an example. You should do it the way Chepner did in the answer: use a data literal with the entries on separate lines.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dict display, but the display doesn't need to be on *one* line.

```
my_dict = {
    'key1': "value1",
    'key2': "value2",
    'key3': "value3",
    ...
}
```

(If PyCharm complains about *that*, you can just ignore it.)